# How can I operate 2 XServes and 2 iMacs from 1 keyboard and 1 mouse (both bluetooth)?

Tags: imac, mouse, xserve, kvm, keyboard

I have 2 Xserves and 2 iMacs.  I would like to control them with 1 Apple wireless keyboard and one Apple Magic Mouse.

I have seen a device from IOGear a [Bluetooth 2.1 USB Micro Adapter](http://www.iogear.com/product/GBU421/),  which made me wonder if something like the following could work:

[image: Overview]

To do this I would need two 1 x 4 passive usb hubs with some kind of electronic or mechanical switch.  Then, plugging the bluetooth to usb adapters into each such device I could pair the keyboard or mouse with the respective bluetooth to usb adapter.

Do any such switchable usb hubs exist?  Could I use anything else?  Since I can readily share the displays of my iMacs via a mini dvi connection to the XServes I don't really need a full blown KVM device.

I saw a post on this site that recommended [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to do something like this, but as I don't have dedicated monitors for the servers, it does not look like a good solution for me.

Any other solutions welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ARD not an option?

Comment: You should be able to do this with only one USB bluetooth adapter and USB switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like this may work, as noted here [Share your Magic Mouse between 2 Macs](http://www.macgeekblog.com/blog/archive/2010/01/23/share-your-magic-mouse-between-2-machintosh-computers.html).  This should be able to be extended to where both the keyboard and the mouse are Bluetooth and replacing the KVM with a USB switch.

> For the setup we used the following hardware:
>
> - 1 mac mini (running 24/7 as a home server)
> - 1 Mac Pro (it’s a hackintosh inside a Mac Pro case)
> - 1 Apple USB Keyboard and 1 dual-link DVI Monitor
> - 1 Apple Magic Mouse (Bluetooth)
> - 1 Belkin Flip KVM Switch (DVI-D 2-Port)
> - 1 small Bluetooth 2.0 USB dongle

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of synergy for my laptop (macbook pro), and workstation (ubuntu linux). To get to my servers (some freebsd, some linux) I use just SSH, but if I need an X session I can export it over ssh. As Lyken mentions, ARD is the way to go. VNC is more crossplatform, but since you're running all Macs, its a piece of piss to get working.

Synergy would be worth a go with your two iMacs.

With that setup, you won't need any extra hardware, just a working network.

Comment: Do you experience any latency when using ARD or Synergy?

Comment: For Synergy, not at all. VNC/ARD, some but its exporting a whole screen, so it has to round trip with the image. Synergy is only sending mouse/keyb movements.