# Multi-user trackpad 2 support

Tags: magic-trackpad

My spouse and I share a Thunderbolt Display but we each have our own MBP, I work from home in the daytime and she uses it in the evening for online night classes in school.

This works great because all of the peripherals are attached to the display. Keyboard, printer, external drive, etc - just plug in a single cable and good to go. The exception to this is the Magic Trackpad. We eventually broke down and got two because of the hassle of unpairing and repairing it since it [doesn't support being paired to multiple computers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41641/how-can-i-pair-my-magic-trackpad-with-multiple-macs).

With the Trackpad 2, it has a lightning connection and according to [the product page](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ2R2LL/A/magic-trackpad-2), "Magic Trackpad 2 pairs automatically with your Mac, so you can get to work right away."

If I have a Trackpad 2 and leave it connected to the Thunderbolt display all of the time, will it "just work", no pairing funny business, and essentially act like a USB trackpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my Magic Trackpad 2 arrived and yes, when plugged in with USB, it acts exactly as I expected it to. The Trackpad still supports bluetooth, but when connected with USB, that takes precedence.