# Magic trackpad starts pairing but does not complete succesfully with one Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have two Macbook pro retina's:

- MbPro 15" retina late 2015 El Capitan
- MbPro 15" retina mid 2012 El Capitan

The first one is able to pair with the `Magic Trackpad` (*not* the "2" - instead the older version).

But the 2012 one has the following behavior:

- initially detects the trackpad -including showing the serial #
- but then cannot complete the pairing - and I'm back to square one.

The initial detection of the trackpad happened several times.

[image]

But usually I do not even get that far: the trackpad is simply not detected.

There is obviously no problem with signal or batteries (new): the trackpad works all day on the other MBPro.

What should I look for as potential culprits and fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a related question and answer: apparently the trackpad can only be paired with one mac at a time - even if the other one were powered off (as is the case here)

[How can I pair my Magic Trackpad with multiple Macs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41641/how-can-i-pair-my-magic-trackpad-with-multiple-macs)